# how to convert int with str('123') to int

Tags: python-3.x, string, int, converters

For example, before:

```
a = {'a': '1234', 'b': 'asdf', 'c': '456'}
```

after:

```
a = {'a': 1234, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 456}
```

rotating a, I want to make `int` if it can convert int.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

A dict-comprehension is good for this task, and you can use `str.isdigit()` to check if a string is numeric before converting it to `int`:

```
new_a = {k : int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for k, v in a.items()} 

print(new_a)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1234, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 456}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'a': '1234', 'b': 'asdf', 'c': '456'}
for i in a:
    try:
        b=int(a[i])
        a[i]=b
    except:
        pass

print(a)
```

In fact `try`/`except` is troll but its another way.